# Display DB location in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm seting up a POC on Azure Cosmos DB Geo-replication.  I would like my sample app to display the data center from which the data is read.  With this I can easy test the geo-location and failover by testing the same app from different geographic locations.

Any idea if the location of the data center is exposed in any if the api's?

Comment: Did you find a way to get the data center info?

Answer (score 0):

There's a `ReadEndpoint` property, which returns the current read endpoint that will be used, based on the endpoint list & priorities you provide when setting up your document client.

Not sure which language you're using, but in c# it's a property of `DocumentClient`, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readendpoint.aspx).

Note: this endpoint's value can change, based on read region availability.

Comment: Yes, I found this method of DocumentClient.  It works, however, I'm not sure if is returning the primary read endpoint or the actual data center used to retrieve the data.  According to the documentation, it is supposed to use the data center closest to the calling IP address.  "Using Azure Cosmos DB's multi-homing APIs, the app always knows where the nearest region is and will send requests to the nearest data center..." When I tested this from a machine away from the primary read data center it still showed up as the primary and not one of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might still help someone.
From what I've seen, cosmo db doesn't hit the closest region as mentioned in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally

Rather, you have to set an ordered regional preference your app needs to read from
It's available in **DocumentClient.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations**
Refer to this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api

If PreferredLocations is not set, it defaults to read from the write region.